# JHipster GitLab CI Permission denied

Tags: heroku, gitlab, jhipster

I use the command "#jhipster ci-cd" to generate the file .gitlab-ci.yml for pushing on Gitlab and deploy to Heroku.

But the maven compile is failed for "./mvnw: Permission denied"

```
Checking out a5400e45 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Checking cache for master...
FATAL: file does not exist                         
Failed to extract cache
$ export MAVEN_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.maven
$ ./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:install-node-and-npm -DnodeVersion=v10.13.0 -DnpmVersion=6.4.1 -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
/bin/bash: line 73: ./mvnw: Permission denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

i don't know why the permission is denied.
I use windows 10 for create jhipster project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your .gitlab-ci.yml file put:

```
image: openjdk:8

[ ... ]

before_script:
    - chmod +x mvnw
    - export MAVEN_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.maven
    - ./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:install-node-and-npm -DnodeVersion=v10.13.0 -DnpmVersion=6.4.1 -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
    - ./mvnw com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:npm -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
```

Comment: The permission thing might be because using windows 10. Usually the execute permission should be in the git repository as I do not need the `chmod` in an example project. Maybe we should add that as comment to the generated gitlab ci config.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR;
Run the following command in you local machine under you project folder:

```sh
git update-index --chmod=+x mvnw
```

Make sure that the script `chmod +x mvnw` is **removed** from your .gitlab-ci.yml file.
Push the changes and then everything will works fine.

---

I have tried the solution mentioned in the other answer which is run `chmod +x mvnw` in `before_script` part but it does not work because the `chmod` is not permitted.

This problem has been dicussed in the jhipster generator github repository [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9391#issuecomment-470815816). Go through the page then you'll find the solution.